# AVPlayer - get the list of available bandwidth/bitrate streams and force one of them

Tags: video-streaming, avfoundation, http-live-streaming

I'm trying to change the playback bitrate while the video is playing dynamically on iOS AVFoundation.
In this stream: https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/streaming/examples/bipbop_16x9/bipbop_16x9_variant.m3u8, there are 5 video bitrates and now the AV chooses the bitrate automatically.

I want to allow the user to select HD quality, so I need a way to force the player to choose the highest bitrate without replacing the source.

Comment: Hi, @Itay Kinnrot did yo solved? If you so, please share your knowledge with us. Best.

Answer (score 2):

The Apple's documentation for `[AVPlayerItem]` (see [docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avplayeritem#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVPlayerItem/preferredPeakBitRate)) has the `preferredPeakBitRate:` method described as:

> The desired limit, in bits per second, of network bandwidth consumption for this item.
>
> If network bandwidth consumption cannot be lowered to meet the preferredPeakBitRate, it will be reduced as much as possible while continuing to play the item.
>
> ---
>
> *AVPlayerItem: Configuring Network Behaviour* [online]. [cit. 2017-02-14]. Available from: https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avplayeritem

It isn't hard-limit per say, but if the connection can support the bitrate (as deemed by the iOS) then it tries to meet the expectations.

As for the list of available bitrates you would need to manually parse the `m3u8` file or just create the levels yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have playlist with multiple variants and bitrates for HLS with ABR:

[image: playlist example]

As of **iOS 15** you can get playlist variants with bitrates, frame rates and video resolution on your `AVURLAsset` likewise:

```
if let asset: AVURLAsset = asset {
    let variants = asset.variants
    for variant in variants {
        let bitrate = variant.averageBitRate
        let videoResolution = variant.videoAttributes?.presentationSize
        let frameRate = variant.videoAttributes?.nominalFrameRate
    }
}
```

Comment: For iOS 14 or less you're out of luck. Only way I found was to parse the manifest.